# Photoshop отказывается открывать PSD-файл

Tags: файлы, восстановление

Ошибка при открытий файла сохранного в PSD. Фотошоп выдает сообщение:

> could not: complete your request because the file is not compatible with this version of photoshop

Характеристики файла: 3000х2000 150 dpi 980mb.

- Пробовал восстанавливать программами, но итог всех действий это однослойные картинки.
- Пробовал создать новый документ. Все работает до момента сохранения.
- Пробовал переустановить программу.
- Пробовал работать с доками, через другие программы, там все хорошо. Но у меня есть пару файлов, на которые я потратил уйму времени и сил.

Собственно, интересует, если не исправление повреждения psd, то хотя бы его открытие для извлечения слоев.

Comment: Хотел дать ссылку на https://www.psd.repair/ru/psd  но утилита уже перестала быть бесплатной.  У вас, кстати, какие первые 4 символа в файле? 8BPS?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он не относится к программированию или администрированию

Answer (score -1):

*Этот ответ основан на сообщении участника @danglebko, которое модераторы сочли неприемлемым по ошибке.*

Попробуйте исправить повреждение вашего PSD-изображения утилитой [Photoshop Fix Toolbox](https://www.fixtoolbox.com/ru/photoshopfix.html), там должна быть пробная версия. У вас проблема связана с высоким пиксельным разрешением и большим объёмом файла.

- Обновление характеристик компьютера должно помочь, но самым рациональным будет копирование дубляжей.
- Попытайтесь сохранить сохранить как .PSD на другом носителе - жёстком / внешнем.
  Есть подозрение на дефекты жёсткого диска.